# sql query seems to return no result

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Certain queries that work fine in the mysql command line client don't seem to return
anything at all (no error, no result) in  phpMyAdmin.
I get the impression it's related to nested queries.
Here's an example:

```
select * from  
  (select  
   (select min(data) from census2 where  
    census2.monkey=samplecollection.monkeyid and  
    date(collectiontime)=date(census2.timestamp)) census  
 from samplecollection,biograph,hormone,plate  
 where plate.hormone='Testosterone' and hormone.plateid=plate.plateid and  
 not specialcontentcode like '%UR%' and thermos!='F' and  
 biograph.id=monkeyid and samplecollection.sampleid=hormone.sampleid)  
 t1 limit 3; 
+--------+ 
| census | 
+--------+ 
| GFF    |    
| GRF    |    
| GRF    |    
+--------+   
3 rows in set (5.09 sec)
```

If I extract the inner query (and put the limit on it) then I get a result.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your query if too complex and clearly not optimized and it may cause the problem you've releved.

Here is the same query with a bit of refactoring:

```
SELECT *
FROM samplecollection SC
INNER JOIN (SELECT C2.monkeyid
                 ,MIN(C2.data) AS [census]
            FROM census2 C2
            INNER JOIN samplecollection SC2 ON SC2.monkeyid = C2.monkey
                                              AND DATE(SC2.collectiontime) = DATE(C2.timestamp)
                                              AND SC2.thermos != 'F'
                                              AND SC2.specialcontentcode NOT LIKE '%UR%'
            GROUP BY C2.monkeyid) T ON T.monkeyid = SC.monkeyid
INNER JOIN biograph B ON B.id = SC.monkeyid
INNER JOIN hormone H ON H.sampleid = SC.sampleid
INNER JOIN plate P ON P.plateid = H.plateid
                     AND P.hormone = 'Testosterone'
LIMIT 3
```

The answer comes late but it may be useful for some people to see how some very complex query structures can be simplified when using `JOIN` clauses.

Hope this will help.